# CasperJS click() cannot dispatch mousedown event error

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS 1.1 and I want to simulate clicking on a file field, but I'm getting an error when I run the test (the project is using AngularJS fwiw):

```
# Create gallery page
PASS File field exists
FAIL Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: input#gallery_file_0
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: spec/javascripts/casperjs/create_gallery.coffee:1323
#    error: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: input#gallery_file_0
#           CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: input#gallery_file_0
#               at mouseEvent (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/modules/casper.js:1323)
#               at click (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/modules/casper.js:428)
#               at spec/javascripts/casperjs/create_gallery.coffee:7
#               at runStep (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/modules/casper.js:1523)
#               at checkStep (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/modules/casper.js:368)
#    stack: not provided
```

The error doesn't make sense to me, because my previous assertion that the input field exists is actually true. Here is the test file:

```
casper.test.begin "Create gallery page", 1, (test) ->

  casper.start "http://localhost:3000/galleries/new", ->

    @then ->
      test.assertField("input#gallery_file_0", null, "File field exists")
      @click("input#gallery_file_0")


  casper.run()
```

What might be the problem?

Versions:

```
casperjs --version
1.1.0-DEV

phantomjs -v
1.9.1

MacOSX 10.8.4
```

Comment: What version of CasperJS and PhantomJS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following line, it looks as though you are actually checking if the value of the field is `null`, which appears to be true when the field doesn't exist.

```
test.assertField("input#gallery_file_0", null, "File field exists")
```

Instead, you should probably use:

```
test.assertExists("input#gallery_file_0", "File field exists");
```

Comment: Good point! I assumed that "assertField" is "assertExists" but for input fields. They should really call it "assertFieldValue" imo.